# LinkedIn shareArticle thumbnail

Tags: social-networking, linkedin-api

how can you specify which image you want to show on when sharing an article? Now it just picks random images from our site which aren't relevant. I tried adding an image_src link to the head of my site but this didn't help. Any idea how you can do this?

The API of LinkedIn doesn't tell us how:
http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1075

Kind regards,

Daan

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no way to specify a thumbnail. They don't seem to use oEmbed, OpenGraph or image_src. However, you can trick it into picking a specific image.

Make your image 62x62 pixels (other sizes will likely work, but non-square aspect ratios failed for us in the combinations we tried). Also, make it the first IMG tag in the document.

If you don't want users to see that image on your site, you can hide it with postion:absolute and right:-999px.

Comment: This is the only solution that I've found that's worked for me. I'm using the AddThis service with OpenGraph tags in the header. These work for Facebook but not for LinkedIn. Putting a special, hidden, 62x62px image for LinkedIn worked, BUT I had to insert it right under the AddThis widget in the code. Putting it at the top of the page didn't work for me.